# Get Folder file directory Ignore top hierarchy from selected folder

Tags: c#

using this line of code to get folder directory

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\", "*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

returns

```
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\COPYING.evaluation
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\Global.asax
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.deploy-readme.txt
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.deploy.cmd
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.SetParameters.xml
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.SourceManifest.xml
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.zip
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\packages.config
C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\Web.config
```

required

```
\WebApi\COPYING.evaluation
\WebApi\Global.asax
\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.deploy-readme.txt
\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.deploy.cmd
\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.SetParameters.xml
\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.SourceManifest.xml
\WebApi\MobileUserAgent.zip
\WebApi\packages.config
\WebApi\Web.config
```

any suggestions for that

Comment: Simply String Replacement doesn't work? Post some Code.

Comment: any suggestions now ? question updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var s in fileEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(s)) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(s));
}
```

Or

```
List<string> lst = fileEntries.Select(s => Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(s)) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList<string>();

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `Substring` the results:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\", "*", 
                                            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                .Select(x=> x.Substring( x.IndexOf("\\WebApi"))).ToArray();
```

Comment: if directory  "C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\ "
contain another subdirectory with same name as "WebApi"
in this case "Substring" returns wrong data . Similar happening in my case

Comment: @saliklatif No. The base directory is `C:\Users\Desktop\WebApi\\ ` so the method is going to split by the first occurrence of `\WebApi`